# Is there a way to feed any modern monitor without powering it?

Tags: display, hdmi, usb-3

I am thinking of a MiniPC with a wire to a monitor, without plugging the power as well again for the monitor, but I am reading HDMI, USB3.0, DisplayPort, DisplayLink specs, and they all say it's technically possible, but I don't know how to check if it's actual implementable for a concrete model.

I saw there are some portable USB monitors, which seem cheap, small and so, but I am focused on desktop regular ones which come with DVI,HDMI,USB3.0,DisplayPort...

I pretty much understand USB3.1 will be specifically designed for this, but I am just wondering the current state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An important consideration would be whether the device pushing your HDMI out supported it.  Case in point, the CEC standard for HDMI is not implemented on most graphics cards (not that this has to do with power, but it speaks to the rigor with which the published spec is implemented).

But, as for USB powered, check here: https://www.google.com/search?q=USB+powered+monitor&newwindow=1&safe=active&es_sm=93&biw=1680&bih=965&source=univ&tbm=shop&tbo=u&sa=X&ved=0CB0QsxhqFQoTCL6MkJ_X2MgCFUY5PgodxeEO_g

I think you'll be pleased.  Same concern applies though - does your mini PC push enough amps (does it meet the USB 3.0 spec) to support a monitor?

Here's a 17" model that claims to be powered by USB: http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/searchtools/item-details.asp?EdpNo=9515519&SRCCODE=WEBGOOPA&scid=scplp1932193&gclid=COHxy97X2MgCFYePHwodVvoN1g

Comment: Nice ! I'm looking into the last one, though I discovered by chance that WiDi thing and I'm flipping out!